# Why or Why NOT to use Sharepoint 2010 as a CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Can someone please list the pros and cons of using Sharepoint as a CMS? Especially for a site that has a bunch of systems integration and real time data access. 
I believe developing a site in ASP.net MVC3 that you will be able to have tighter systems integration, loose coupling, and greater control over the presentation layer.

Any pros and cons would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If you had just left SharePoint as the tag I think the question would still be open.